# setOpacityTo() with <TouchableOpacity> in react-native

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

How to use the method `setOpacityTo()` with `<TouchableOpacity>` in react-native ?

```
setOpacityTo((value: number), (duration: number));
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.42/touchableopacity.html

Comment: setOpacityTo is no longer available on Touchable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TouchableHighlight ref="touch" onPress={this.onPress}/>

this.refs.touch.setOpacityTo(50);
```

I guess that should work.

When you use the ref prop in any React component, you are basically adding that instance into a global registry of components where they store a reference that you can access later.

The way you access that instance later is by using the this.refs.

That way, you can then call the component method that will set the opacity.

Comment: I think you mean this.refs.touch.setOpacityTo(50) ?

Comment: @sfratini Can you give a little more explanation?

Comment: setOpacityTo is no longer available on Touchable